# Math code division by zero error

Tags: php, system, division, rating

http://puu.sh/h8mkG/d2a994ff38.png

Line 7 says division by zero, even when I type it in google and replace with the values, it's ≈ 0.6377...

Also, on line 9, it says "Function name must be a string".

For reference this is a modified Glicko rating system.

Comment: add a programming language tag, and don't paste a screenshot, but just copy&paste the code, including line numbers, and the full error.

Comment: What language is this? Is `pi` a built in constant?

Comment: It's PHP. I thought it had pi? Maybe it doesn't...

Comment: if "pi" doesn't exist, it will assign a value of 0 to pi.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have `/pi`, when infact you need `pi()`, because this is a undefined variable - it is set to a value of 0, therefore you get the error you're getting. You can't divide by 0.

Furthermore, line 9 should read:

`$d = 1/($q^2*$g^2*$e*(1-$e));`

not

`$d = 1/($q^2*$g^2*$e(1-$e));`

Your issue lied in

`$e(1-$e))`, where you are trying to cast $e as a function with parameters, you need a * between these. You may get a similar issue on line 11 where you've done the same `$g(1...`

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But it still says "function name must be a string" for line 9.

Comment: I've amended my answer @user3040456

Comment: Thanks, that removed the errors. Silly mistake I guess.

Comment: TIL: PHP will set undefined variables to 0 instead of generating an error. I'm in shock.

Comment: @MarcusMüller read "PHP a fractal of bad design" - http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

very interesting read haha